# Estou com um problema com meu código não consigo trazer os dados de uma função para outra!

Tags: c, array, c++, funções

Estou com um problema com meu código não consigo trazer os dados de uma função para outra!!

no caso da Função somar não consigo imprimi-la na função imprimir.

Alguém pode me ajudar

1 - Inserir em um vetor
2 - Somar valores do vetor
3 - Imprimir valores e soma
4 - Sair

A qualquer momento pode solicitar impressão dos dados, não imprima lixo de memória
A qualquer momento pode solicitar a soma, não some valores não lidos ainda

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5
int vetor[TAM];
int menu(){
    int opcao;
    printf("1 - Inserir\n");
    printf("2 - Somar valores\n");
    printf("3 - Imprimir\n");
    printf("4 - Sair\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    return opcao;
}
//----------------------------------------------------INSERINDO OS DADOS
int inserir(int i){ 
    int vt;
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    return vt;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------SOMAR
int somar(int i){
    int soma=0, total;
    for (i=0; i<TAM; i++){
        soma=soma+vetor[i];
    }
    total = soma;
    printf("\n");
    return total;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------------------------------------------------IMPRIMINDO OS DADOS
void imprimir(int i){
    printf("Imprimindo elementos\n");
    for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++){
        printf("   %d   ", vetor[i]);
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", total);   //IMPRIMIR DADO DA SOMA <----------------
    printf("\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(){
    int op = 0, i=0;
    i++;
    while(op != 4){
        op = menu();
        switch (op){
            case 1:
                inserir(i);
                break;
            case 2:
                somar(i);
                break;
            case 3:
                imprimir(i);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Saindo");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No seu código eu achei 2 erros, que foram:

- Não chamar a função somar dentro da função imprimir
- Não declarar a variável TOTAL

As correções foram basicamente isso que citei acima e seu código funcionou

```
    void imprimir(int i){
    int total;
    printf("Imprimindo elementos\n");
    for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++){
        printf("   %d   ", vetor[i]);
    }
    total = somar(i);
    printf("%d\n", total);   //IMPRIMIR DADO DA SOMA <----------------
    printf("\n");
}
```

Como não havia uma troca do valor entre a função somar e a função imprimir, sempre era impresso lixo de memória. Logo, chamando a função, passando por parâmetro qualquer coisa, ele retornou a soma corretamente.

Comment: Perfeitamente, mil perdões

Comment: Mario se quiser deixar uma mensagem disponibilizando-se para ajuda use os comentários.